# Chaning the Fieldname dynamic extjs 6

Tags: javascript, extjs, extjs6

```
xtype: 'hidden/text/textarea',
name: 'somename',
reference: 'somereference',
```

How do i change the name of dynamically 
i have tried

```
typeId.inputEl.dom.name = 'typeId[1]';
```

but it is not working
i am using extjs
[image: here] is the inspector image

as image name can be seen as `result[1255]` but when posting it is posting the old name as `result`;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that "typeId" is your form field, you only have changed the name of the underlying dom element, but you also need to set the name for the ExtJS component:

```js
typeId.name = 'newName';
```

Check out this example: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/1ngu

1. Open the "Network" tab in dev tools
2. Do a form submit by accessing "Form Submit"
3. Access "Change field name"
4. Do a form submit again and observe that the submitted name has changed

Comment: By _posting_ you mean using `form.submit()`?

Comment: Although the answer you gave didn't solve my problem, I'll still accept it.

Comment: Can you create a fiddle so I can better understand your problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132171/discussion-between-scebotari-and-waqar-haider).

Comment: I have changed my Form, now creating the whole form dynamically and so no need to change the name of each field dynamically
Thanks by the way